# Start fish shell with different config folder

Tags: shell, fish

Is it possible to start `fish` shell to point to another config directory, then the default `~/.config/fish`?

I am trying to have same-behaving shell experience in multi-user system across different users (eq. while `sudo -u <user> fish` have the same aliases/functions etc. like under my user). But also have this in non-persistant way as other users in the system might not be interested in my settings.

So far my ideas were:

1. source my config ==> problem with auto-load functions not available (eq. `~/.config/fish/functions/`)
2. symlink my config dir ==> not a non-persistant, but so far closest functional solution

Answer (score 4):

It's clear from your comments to the answer provided by Glenn that your original question left out some important information. If you're working on a system that has other users that will also `sudo -u $some_user` you should not symlink to your personal config files. Instead just leverage the fact that fish is compliant with the XDG Base Directory specification. Simply set env var `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to your real home dir before starting fish. For example,

```
sudo -u $some_user /bin/sh -c "XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config fish"
```

Comment: Brilliant. Then the OP can create a function to encapsulate that: `function become -a some_user; sudo -u $some_user /bin/sh -c "XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/.config fish"; end` and then simply type `become app1user`

Comment: But you'll need to give these other `some_user`s read+write permission to your home dir and your ~/.config and ~/.config/fish

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the common stuff in a common directory, perhaps

```
/opt/fish_config/config.fish
/opt/fish_config/functions/
/opt/fish_config/completions/
```

Then in any ~/.config/fish/config.fish you can put:

```
source /opt/fish_config/config.fish
```

and in     /opt/fish_config/config.fish, in addition to your own fish stuff, be sure to add:

```
set fish_function_path $fish_function_path /opt/fish_config/functions
set fish_complete_path $fish_complete_path /opt/fish_config/completions
```

Just using a symlink is probably easier, although file permissions might be an issue.

Personally, although I don't share my config across multiple users on the same machine, I share my config across multiple machines: my fish config is in git, and I symlink ~/.config/fish to the git directory.

Comment: Yeah I have my dot files also on Git and it works very nicely for moving the configuration across machines.  If you would like to avoid the symlink to the git directory, there is very neat way that I am using described [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/02/best-way-to-store-dotfiles-git-bare-repo/).

Comment: Hmm I was not aware of the `$fish_function_path` and `$fish_complete_path`, that might lead to the solution! The thing is that I don't want to manipulate the switched user's config in anyway, because when another user will then switch to the user, he would be forced to use my setting even though he might not be interested in it...

Comment: This might not be what the OP was asking for, but it's exactly what I needed, thanks.